# Change label text using another class c#

Tags: c#, .net

i am new to c#.net
in need to change label text to JSON parameter string values i tried this way but did not change label text

```
public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    string CounterNo = request.QueryString["counter"];
    string OrderNo = request.QueryString["order"];
    DisplayValue(CounterNo, OrderNo);       
    return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
}

public static void DisplayValue(string odr, string cntr)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.lblCounter.Text = cntr;
    frm.lblOrder.Text = odr;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Replace Application.DoEvents() with frm.ShowDialog()

Comment: You should never ever call Application.DoEvents().

Comment: when try with frm.ShowDialog() opening a new form i want to change only label text on same form how can i try this?  Thanks

Comment: Please add the the code for the form and what label you're trying to update - it's not clear what problem you're having.